# Good way to prevent access to Django site if JavaScript and cookies disabled?

Tags: javascript, django, cookies, django-templates, django-views

I'm building a Django site using responsive web design and RESS.  I want to prevent the user from accessing the site if they have JavaScript and/or cookies disabled in their browser.  Is the code shown below a good way to implement this?  Is there any way I can improve the code?  Finally, will there be any performance hit?  I would think there would be to the extent that the server would have needlessly downloaded code to a browser that has JS disabled.  However, I figure that, after the user has accessed the site once, they'll know they need JS enabled to use it.

I guess I'm more concerned about whether there will be any significant latency given that this check would be run every time a user accesses any page on the site.  Since the site will be used on mobile devices, speed is a primary concern.

Thanks.

```
# static/styles.css:
<style type="text/css">
    #page-content, #cookie-warning {
          display: none;
    }
</style>


# templates/base.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>RWD/RESS Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/styles.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <noscript>WARNING: You must enable JavaScript in your browser in order to use this website.</noscript>
    <div id="cookie-warning">
        WARNING: You must enable cookies to use this site.
    </div>

    <div id="page-content">
        {% block body_wrapper %} {% endblock %}
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Functions to test capabilities
        var javascript_enabled = function () {
            // var elem = document.getElementById("page-content");
            return true;
        };
        var cookies_enabled = function() {
            var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;
            if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled) {
                document.cookie = "test_cookie";
                cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("test_cookie") != -1) ? true : false;
            }
            return cookieEnabled;
        };
        // Function to allow multiple onload event listeners
        function addLoadEvent(func) {
            var oldOnLoad = window.onload;
            if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
                window.onload = func;
            } else {
                window.onload = function() {
                    if (oldOnLoad) {
                        oldOnLoad();
                    }
                    func();
                }
            }
        }

        // Add onload events for capability functions.
        addLoadEvent(cookies_enabled);
        addLoadEvent(javascript_enabled);

        // Toggle page content or warning messages.
        if (javascript_enabled() === true) {
            var pageContentElem = document.getElementById("page-content");
            if (cookies_enabled() === true) {
                pageContentElem.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                var cookieWarningElem = document.getElementById("cookie-warning");
                cookieWarningElem.style.display = "block";
                pageContentElem.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>

# templates/some_page.html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body_wrapper %}
    {# content goes here #}
{% endblock body_wrapper%}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`<noscript>`](http://www.quackit.com/html_5/tags/html_noscript_tag.cfm) tag:

In the `base.html`,

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<noscript>
    <h3>Javascript is disabled</h3>
    <style type="text/css">
       #main {display: none; } 
    </style>
</noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(!navigator.CookieEnabled){
     document.getElementById('main').innerHtml = "Cookies are disabled";
  }
</script>

<div id="main">
    {# This has the body's main content. #}
</div>

</body>
</html>
```